# CIDR entries and routing tables

Tags: networking, cidr

I have a question which asks the following:

> Suppose a router has the following CIDR entries in its routing table:
>
> ```
> Net/Preﬁx Next Hop
> 128.96.39.0/24 Interface 0
> 128.96.39.128/25 Interface 1
> 128.96.40.0/25 Router 2
> 192.4.153.0/26 Router 3
> default Router 4
> ```
>
> For each of the following IP addresses, what does the router do if a packet
>       with that address arrives?
>
> 1. 128.96.39.10;
> 2. 128.96.40.12;
> 3. 128.96.39.151;
> 4. 192.4.153.17;
> 5. 192.4.153.90.

I know that `/24` means that 24 bits are assigned to the network address meaning that 8 bits are assigned to hosts. How do I get the subnet mask from the IP address represented in decimal and then from there determine where the IP would go?

Comment: You can find a table [here](http://www.oav.net/mirrors/cidr.html), but it's basically common sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Router takes the route with the longest fitting subnet mask.

(i) interface 0
(ii) Router 2
(iii) interface 1
(iv) Router 3
(v) Router 4

Comment: What do you mean exactly. the first 3 parts of the first IP (i) match Interface 0 and Interface 1. Why did it go to Interface 0?

Comment: The second entry has a /25 -> 128 hosts - 2. It starts at .129. So a host cannot get a .10 IP address in this subnet

Answer (score 3):

Well, the most specific subnet is always used first:

/25 is more specific then /24. In your example, this would mean:

1. interface 0
2. Router 2
3. interface 1
4. Router 3
5. Router 4